# SQL Filter on multiple columns with possible 'all' value

Tags: sql-server

Apologies if this question has been asked before. I have searched this website, but didn't find an answer.

I have a table with approx. 15 fields. Most of these are foreign keys to other tables (properties) like this:

```
Table MyObject
name nvarchar(500)
property_1_id int 
property_2_id int 
.....   
property_15_id int

Table Property_1
id int 
name nvarchar(50)

Table Property_2
id int
name nvarchar(50)

.. etc
```

Now I have to make an application that allows the user to filter on any of these properties, using a combination of dropdown lists. These lists contain the values of the other tables, and an extra value: 'All'.

How can I construct my query so it accepts these 15 fields as parameters, with the value either being a real value, or '-1' meaning 'all', and then filter the appropriate records?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
SELECT Property_1, Property_2 FROM MyObject
WHERE  (Property_1 = @Property_1 OR @Property_1 = -1)
   AND (Property_2 = @Property_2 OR @Property_2 = -1)
```

Add more `AND` statements for each of your Properties

Whenever a parameter is set to `-1` the corresponding `AND` clause will always evaluate to true thus returning any value for that property.

A sample T-SQL Script with 5 parameters shown below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EnterYourSprocNameHere]
    @property_1    INT  = -1
   ,@property_2    INT  = -1
   ,@property_3    INT  = -1
   ,@property_4    INT  = -1
   ,@property_5    INT  = -1
AS
BEGIN

SELECT property_1, property_2, property_3, property_4, property_5
    FROM MyObject
     WHERE  (Property_1 = @property_1 OR @property_1 = -1)
        AND (Property_2 = @property_2 OR @property_2 = -1)
        AND (Property_3 = @property_3 OR @property_3 = -1)
        AND (Property_4 = @property_4 OR @property_4 = -1)
        AND (Property_5 = @property_5 OR @property_5 = -1)

END
```

If you want to pass null instead of -1 then use this script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EnterYourSprocNameHere]
    @property_1    INT  = NULL
   ,@property_2    INT  = NULL
   ,@property_3    INT  = NULL
   ,@property_4    INT  = NULL
   ,@property_5    INT  = NULL
 AS
 BEGIN

SELECT property_1, property_2, property_3, property_4, property_5
    FROM MyObject
     WHERE  (Property_1 = @property_1 OR @property_1 IS NULL)
        AND (Property_2 = @property_2 OR @property_2 IS NULL)
        AND (Property_3 = @property_3 OR @property_3 IS NULL)
        AND (Property_4 = @property_4 OR @property_4 IS NULL)
        AND (Property_5 = @property_5 OR @property_5 IS NULL)

END
```

Comment: If you have already set the default value for every parameter as -1, then why did you explicitly add the OR condition with @preperty_1=-1. This is not necessary right?

Comment: Yes it is necessary, the -1 is a default for the parameter should it not be explicitly passed when executing the stored procedure. If you don't have the @property_ = -1 `OR` condition then SQL Server will try and match the contents of the `Property_1` field to `-1` which will likely return zero matches rather than all values as the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

If you can send NULL value instead of -1, you can use ISNULL function.

```
SELECT Property_1, Property_2, Property_3
FROM MyObject
WHERE  Property_1 = ISNULL(@Property_1, Property_1)
    AND Property_2 = ISNULL(@Property_2, Property_2)
    AND Property_3 = ISNULL(@Property_3, Property_3)
    ...
    ..
    .;
```

Comment: (off topic) Please stop saying "improved formatting" in your edit summary when you do not improve any formatting at all. ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2198361), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2197764), etc.)

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I mean about question formatting, not about code formatting. I'll be more careful.